# ABP Framework - how to intercept all the requests

Tags: c#, abp

I am new to this framework and i have to intercept all the requests. Is there a way to use AbpModule or ApplicationService to check all the requests?
Thanks.

Comment: Check all the requests and do what? Log it? Add some custom authentication? Modify routing? If you're new to ASP.NET Core, don't use ABP. It does have a long list of "best practice implementations" that aren't really good or even necessary. You won't understand how ASP.NET Core really works or what needs customizing for logging, authentication, routing, or anything else that you may have in mind. ABP can't change how ASP.NET Core works, so you *do* need to know what feature needs to change, whether you use ABP or not

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the "OnApplicationInitialization" method of your module by using this code.

```cs
// All requests blocked by custom code
        app.Use( (context, next) =>
        {
            // custom code
            var request = context.Request;
            var @continue = false;
            if(@continue)
            {
                return next();
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        });
```